# Algorithm to Move / Rotate Points

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, drawing, graph-algorithm

What is the algorithm to move / "rotate" a point in the (x, y) coordinate by x degrees relative to (0, 0)? For example, in the picture below, I want to move point A to B, by x degrees; the distance between A and (0, 0) should be the same between B and (0, 0).

I need to do in a front-end environment i.e. JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: This question was part of my learning about how to draw a polygon on a canvas. In case it'd be helpful for other, here's a formula to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340972/583539.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B.x = A.x * cos(x) - A.y * sin(x)
B.y = A.x * sin(x) + A.y * cos(x)
```

`x` is assumed to be in radians, you must convert otherwise.

Comment: +1 Yep, and as an aside:  var Seriously =  Time-to-draw-OPs-nice-image > Time-for-him-to-google-answer;

Comment: @markE, the first time I had to answer this question for myself there was no Google, there wasn't even an internet. I figured it out from basic trig. How times have changed!

Answer (score 0):

To help with a lot of Canvas (or just JavaScript) transformations I made a small Transformation class that can apply any kind of arbitrary transformation (Rotation, scale, translation) to a given point.

This is very useful when you need math to mimic the transformation matrix on the Canvas.

https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js

To rotate a point with it you'd do:

```
var t = new Transform();
t.rotate(5); // some number of radians
t.transformPoint(ax, ay); // returns [bx, by]
```